# Unexpected @Adjust formula behaviour

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-formula

I've got a task, to calculate end date of validity period for an object.

Let's say start date of validity is: `18 Sept. 2014`

Validity period (for example) is: `3 months`

End date (last date when object is still valid, + 3 months and -1 day): `17 Dec 2014`

Looks correct, and to calcuate end date I used the following @-formula:

```
@Adjust(start; 0; 3; -1; 0; 0; 0);
```

where I add `3` months and decrease `1` day from the start date.

But when I set start date as `01 Oct. 2014` I get end date `30 Dec 2014` instead of `31 Dec 2014`.

Looks strange and looks like a bug in the Lotus Notes engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was a bit unexpected and simple.

`@Adjust` function evaluates it's parameters **from right to left**.

In other words it decreases `1 day` and then adds `3 months` to the start date.

And if start date is `01 Oct 2014`, then `@Adjust` formula gets `30 Sept. 2014` by adding `-1 day` and then adds `3 months` and get `30 Dec 2014`.

And to solve this issue I needed to change the initial formula:

to

```
temp_ := @Adjust(start; 0; 3; 0; 0; 0; 0);
@Adjust(temp_; 0; 0; -1; 0; 0; 0);
```

`temp_` variable gets start date increased to 3 months, and only after that we decrease 1 day from the calculation result.